# stream provider can't seem to update the ui as intended

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'm working on a Flutter application using Riverpod for state management and Firestore for database interaction. I have a StreamProvider (**`allPostsProvider`**) that fetches posts from Firestore and provides them to the UI.

```
// Define a Riverpod provider for a stream of posts
final allPostsProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Iterable<Post>>(
  (ref) {
    // Create a StreamController to manage the stream
    final controller = StreamController<Iterable<Post>>();

    // Set up a listener on the "posts" collection in Firestore
    final sub = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(
          FirebaseCollectionName.posts,
        )
        .orderBy(
          FirebaseFieldNames.createdAt,
          descending: true,
        )
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
      (snapshots) {
        // Convert the document snapshots to Post objects and add them to the stream
        final posts = snapshots.docs.map(
          (doc) => Post(
            postId: doc.id,
            json: doc.data(),
          ),
        );

        controller.sink.add(posts);
      },
    );

    // Set up cleanup when the provider is disposed
    ref.onDispose(
      () {
        sub.cancel(); // Cancel the Firestore stream subscription
        controller.close(); // Close the StreamController
      },
    );

    // Return the stream from the StreamController
    return controller.stream;
  },
);
```

here Is how am using the provider

```
class HomeView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final posts = ref.watch(allPostsProvider);

    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
        ref.refresh(allPostsProvider.future);
        return Future.delayed(
          const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
      },
      child: posts.when(
        data: (posts) {
          if (posts.isEmpty) {
            return const EmptyContentsAnimationzwords(
              text: Strings.noPortalsYet,
            );
          } else {
            return PostsGridView(
              posts: posts,
            );
          }
        },
        error: (_, __) {
          // Displaying the error message in the UI
          return const ErrorAnimation();
        },
        loading: () {
          return const LoadingAnimation();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does  ref.refresh(allPostsProvider.future); this function is working when you refresh the pull to refresh?

Comment: Remove the order by for debug and check the results are showing or not?

Comment: nope actually I also tried to remove the .future but it does not do any thing all it does is display the animation when logged the code it suggests that the posts is empty yet everything is stored properly in the database

Comment: Rahul Kushwala thankx when i removed order by everything worked but the problem is it cant query data in descending order because i wanted the latest added data to appear first how can i go about it but again thanx this is some thing that had bantered me for 3 months

Answer (score 0):

https://riverpod.dev/docs/case_studies/pull_to_refresh shows how to do this properly:

```
onRefresh: () => ref.refresh(someProvider.future),
```

Comment: Thanks man i solved the general problem now let me emback on refreshing